# c++ destruct staic variable in function with memory allocation

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, static, destructor

I have little question about c++

how can I destruct this code without memory leak?

```
void classA::funcA()
{
    static char* cArr = new char[10];
}
```

just don't write like this style?

Comment: Really there is no need to call delete.  Yes, it is a memory leak because you don't free the memory but a static variable is only initialized once, meaning you only call `new` once, and the variable doesn't get destroyed until the end of the program and at that point all the memory gets returned to the OS anyways.

Comment: Or use a smart pointer to make sure that it is `delete`ed explicitly. Although, as @NathanOliver has mentioned, it will be `deleted`ed at the end of the program.

Comment: @Gupta It does not get `delete`d, which might be an issue for non-trivial types if you rely on the destructor actually doing something important. For that case OP's question would be much more relevant.

Comment: @walnut You mean the dtor of the static objects are not called for non-trivial types at the end of the program?

Comment: @Gupta The static object's destructor is called, but I mean the case where the static object is a pointer to a non-trivial-destructible object allocated with `new` as in OP's example. That dynamically allocated object's destructor would not be called automatically.

Comment: @Gupta Or maybe I am misreading your comment and you just meant to say that the smart pointer (and with it the managed object) would be deleted at the end of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RAII type instead or avoid allocation:

```
static char cArr[10];
static auto cArr2 = std::make_unique<char[]>(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects in static storage exist for the entire duration of the program.

The pointed dynamic object could be deleted earlier than the program termination,  if you don't use the object for the entire duration. But if that is the case, then why would you own the object through a pointer in static storage?

The fact that the memory is technically leaked when the lifetime of the static pointer ends is not a problem because the program is about to end.

What you should reconsider is whether you need static storage in the first place. If you do change your design to use automatic storage instead, then you must be very careful to not leak the memory.